# Connecting to multiple AMQP brokers

Tags: jms, amqp

I am trying to setup a HA amqp client. There are currently 3 amqps brokers. Currently my client config is as below :

```
<property name="remoteURI" value="amqps://node1:9551?jms.username=XXXXXXXX&amp;jms.password=XXXXXXXXX&amp;transport.trustStoreLocation=etc/keystore.jks" />
```

Now since I have 2 other AMQP brokers too, im trying to connect to them too. Firstly is it possible ? According to [documentation](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-cpp-1.36.0/cpp-broker/book/chapter-ha.html), for python I can try something like :

```
connection = qpid.messaging.Connection.establish("node1", reconnect=True, reconnect_urls=["node1", "node2", "node3"])
```

But for JMS related connection, it states :

```
connectionfactory.qpidConnectionfactory = amqp://guest:guest@clientid/test?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'&failover='failover_exchange'
```

But I dont see any indication on how to connect to other brokers.

Any idea how this can be achieved from client side ?

Comment: It's not entirely clear which AMQP JMS clients you are referring to here so an answer is tricky.  Also your question is confusing as it is unclear if you want failover or a fanout connection.

Comment: So I am using servicemix to route messages between queues. In my SMX config, I am connecting to one of the 3 brokers directly using amqps but I want the ability to connect to all 3 incase one of them fails. And yes, I am looking to configure failover.

Comment: Which still lacks clarification on which AMQP JMS client you are using

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are using the QpidJMS  AMQP v1.0 based client from the Apache Qpid project since you've not given any other information to make a better guess.  The way that client would handle failover configuration is on the connection URI, something like:

```
failover://(amqp://host1:5672,amqp://host2:5672)?jms.username....
```

You can of course find these things out from reading the [documentation](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.27.0/docs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @Tim . Yes you are correct I am using Qpid JMS AMSQPS client. I will try this solution out.